# Listing grouped data in table rows

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I assume I have the following data

```
data() {
    return {
        users: [
            {country: 'USA', name: 'Taylor'},
            {country: 'UK', name: 'Tony'},
            {country: 'USA', name: 'Mary'},
            {country: 'JAPAN', name: 'Jane'},
            {country: 'JAPAN', name: 'Moses'},
            // More users from different countries in the world
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to group by country and my final table structure to be like this, ordered by country name desc.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>User</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">USA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Taylor</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Mary</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Tony</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">JAPAN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Jane</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Moses</td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

How can I achieve this? I have tried playing with Lodash's groupBy but cant achieve it

```
let users = _.groupBy(this.users, function(user) { return user.country })
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one example of how to do it without any libraries.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data:{
    users: [
      {country: 'USA', name: 'Taylor'},
      {country: 'UK', name: 'Tony'},
      {country: 'USA', name: 'Mary'},
      {country: 'JAPAN', name: 'Jane'},
      {country: 'JAPAN', name: 'Moses'},
      // More users from different countries in the world
    ]
  },
  computed:{
    byCountry(){
      return this.users.reduce((acc, user) => {
        (acc[user.country] = acc[user.country] || []).push(user.name)
        return acc
      }, {})
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>User</th>
    </tr>
    <template v-for="people, country in byCountry">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">{{country}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr v-for="person in people">
        <td></td>
        <td>{{person}}</td>
      </tr>
    </template>    
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Template tags don't work in all browsers.  You'd have to turn everything into a flat array in order to use a single `<tr v-for>` otherwise IE wont render this properly

Comment: @Bert I'm using Vue Components and it doesn't allow me 2 root items... thats is <tr></tr><tr></tr>

Comment: @Jeff Your suggestions looks perfect. Can you try it out for me please?

Comment: @richie I'm not sure what you mean about two root items.

Comment: @Bert I cannot have 2 table rows inside the template. If I wrap them with a DIV, it breaks. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/meyrj8nf/

Comment: @richie each grouping is a component for you?

Comment: @Bert Yes. Is it possible?

Comment: @Bert Am actually trying to group games by date. Am developing a betting site. See the result here https://ibb.co/iva8VG

Comment: @Richie Here is an example of using components and flattened. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/KybMoX?editors=1010